# Using a singleton within swift or dependency injection?

Tags: ios, swift

I am pretty new to Swift and iOS development.

I have a repository file currently saving data within and array (later within a database)

This repository will be used within two `UIViewControllers` (One adds data, the other one reads from the repo).

In Java, I would use dependency injection to get the same instance of repository in different classes. In Swift, I don't have dependency injection so the repository currently is a singleton which is used in both `UIViewControllers`.

Is this a good pattern or is it better to use some other pattern/is there a better solution?

Comment: Asking if a singleton is a good pattern on StackOverflow is fraught with danger, as there is wide debate over the pattern. I personally use them in my own projects that are that small, but if you are uncertain about the pattern, would CoreData work for you? That would keep the data consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a subjective question.
But for me it's fine. In all of my applications I have a "DataManager" that is a singleton class that manage the persistant storing stuff.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you can always inject `DataManager` by one way or another, even if this is stored as a singleton for convenience. For example, the view controller initializer could look like this:
`init(dataManager: DataManager = .shared) { self.dataManager = dataManager }`